# Multi-spectral high resolution satellite images for flood events

Tags: geospatial, images, aerial-photography, geohazard, download

I'm searching for multi-spectral high resolution satellite images for flood events.

I found a database of flood events at the [Dartmouth (Colorado) Flood Observatory](http://floodobservatory.colorado.edu/) with dates and approximate locations (polygons) and I used the **Sentinel API hub** to download images. The problem is that images cover too large an area and I cannot find the interesting regions; neither can I get images of the exact same location for two different dates (to compare pre and post events).

Is there a way to get a free dataset of high resolution satellite images for flood events (pre and post disater)?

BTW, I want to apply machine learning algorithms on these images.

Answer (score 1):

In June 2013, the City of Calgary, Alberta [experienced severe flooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Alberta_floods).

The City has made very high resolution orthophoto mosaics available at no cost on their website. The licences specifies non-commercial use - see the links below for the specifics.

One was captured [during the flood](https://cityonline.calgary.ca/Pages/Category.aspx?cat=CITYonlineDefault&category=Orthophotos-Flood(2013)) (not necessarily at the peak) and another was captured [a few months later](https://cityonline.calgary.ca/Pages/Category.aspx?cat=CITYonlineDefault&category=Orthophotos-BySection(2013%20Aug)). Note - this imagery is aerial rather than satellite.